# Youtube v3 API: List Channel's Videos -- Unauthenticated?

Tags: json, api, video, youtube, google-api

## Is it possible to list a Youtube channel's videos without being authenticated?

I was thinking just basic JSON HTTP GET Requests.

**I need to list videos for a Youtube channel that I do not own** -- I intend to present the channel's videos, each with the associated thumbnail, and embedding a Youtube player for a video that the user clicks. The corner will say "Powered by Youtube" or something of that like.

I am doing this on behalf of a client for their Youtube channel, and am wondering if I can avoid the hassle of bothering them for an API key.

It seems *intuitive and obvious* to me that the **listing of a channel's videos is surely *public***, meaning, I shouldn't need to authenticate with an API Key for this. It seems this is so with Youtube's v2 API -- *but I want to be hip with the kids these days and use v3.*

### Updates

This seems easily possible with Youtube's v2 API. Example:

     http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/NationalGeographic/uploads?alt=json

***Surely they didn't just deprecate incredibly convenient, useful, beneficial functionality?***

Answer (score 1):

After digging deeper and wasting a formidable amount of time -- I now understand.

## You don't need the Youtube Channel's API Key. 
*You can use ANY Google API Key*.

I did this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application

I set up a Google API Key, and then set the allowed referrers to my project's domain name. (that way somebody doesn't steal my key and use it by looking at my javascript).

Weirdly though, I'm still receiving results when I query it from different domains.. so the referrer protection seems moot. Regardless, it's unlikely that someone would waste their time taking and abusing my API key when they could get their own for free.

Comment: could you please add an example

Comment: I had the same question, found you use the channel api to get the id of the channel
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername={youtube username}&part=contentDetails&key={your API key here}`

That will return some results with an ID in it for the 'channelId', use that to then request from the search API

Then use the search api to get the list of videos for that channe.
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your API key here}&channelId={ the channel id}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without obtaining API Key using [youtube-dl](http://yt-dl.org/) tool.

`youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist https://www.youtube.com/channel/{channelId}`

It will output json formatted data similar to:

```
{"_type": "url", "url": "HQxZaeGxwQs", "ie_key": "Youtube", "id": "HQxZaeGxwQs", "title": "Episode 6"}
{"_type": "url", "url": "t1itLpsgnnc", "ie_key": "Youtube", "id": "t1itLpsgnnc", "title": "Stack Overflow Podcast Episode 7"}
```

[Source](https://archive.zhimingwang.org/blog/2014-11-05-list-youtube-playlist-with-youtube-dl.html)